# TypeScript: Infer argument types for Window.setTimeout

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The types for `Window.setTimeout` are defined in `lib.d.ts` as:

```js
declare function setTimeout(
  handler: TimerHandler, 
  timeout?: number, 
  ...arguments: any[]
): number;
```

I'd like to extend the types such that the `arguments` type is inferred from the handler instead of an `any[]`

Something like this:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    setTimeout<THandler extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
      handler: THandler,
      timeout?: number,
      ...arguments: Parameters<THandler>
    ): number;
  }
}
```

The above works, but requires me to explicitly provide the generic `THandler` type.

For example:

```js
declare function doSomething(value: number): number;

setTimeout(
  doSomething,
  100,
  'john', // compiler doesn't complain that this is a string
);

setTimeout<typeof doSomething>(
  doSomething,
  100,
  'john', // compiler complains as expected
);
```

Is there a way to get `setTimeout` to infer the `THandler` argument based on the handler passed to it?

Comment: Based on the [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqp3rN) that I added as an edit, it appears to be because the original function definition, which allowed `...any[]`, is treated as an overload, and therefore is allowed. Only when you explicitly define the generic does it use the one you've added.

Comment: @Samathingamajig The Playground that you added doesn't seem to recognize the generic overload at all which is not what I see locally. Are you able to see the overload with the generic arg?

Comment: @bingles I've updated your playgroung, you can't `window` it - `window extends globalThis` but `globalThis` is not `Window`

Comment: @bingles see my answer, I had to add `window.` to each since it was in the window namespace-ish thing. Extending Window adds things to `window.*`, not global functions.

Comment: :thinking: well yes but it just doesn't work in playground because `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations` so it has to have `export { }` to be `es module` making Window things not going to global

Comment: @Dimava I think the types you are referring to are the NodeJS types and not the lib.d.ts ones. The playground also doesn't reflect what I see locally, so I think the link should be removed.

Comment: lol playground was not even yours. Rollbacked. I will change `args: unknown[]` tho as it's an obvious typo

Answer (score 0):

Based on the TypeScript Playground that I added as an edit, it appears to be because the original function definition, which allowed `...any[]`, is treated as an overload, and therefore is allowed. Only when you explicitly define the generic does it use the one you've added.

Here's an updated link with more tests: https://tsplay.dev/NBV5xN

I also had to modify your code from `unknown[]` to `any[]` because of other errors, but it makes sense because unknown means "I don't know what type this is, treat it as nothing until further notice" while any means "I don't know what type this is, it could be anything, disable type checking for now", and `extends` makes a tighter version once it has more information.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    setTimeout<THandler extends (...args: any[]) => unknown>(
      handler: THandler,
      timeout?: number,
      ...arguments: Parameters<THandler>
    ): number;
  }
}
```

Here's that code, showing the type inference by TypeScript

[image]

Looks like removing an overload from an interface is not allowed: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19064